# Why does Jenkins/Maven give this error

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

It's kinda weird. I'm getting a huge error, and have got no clue where it comes from / how to fix.
The error:

```
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project Sortal: Compilation failure
cause : Compilation failure
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project Sortal: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:112)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 27 more
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

I set up the project as a Maven project, let it build when it gets a push-notification from Github (and it builds, so that's not a problem), and my pom.xml doesn't contain any errors.
How to fix this?

Comment: Are you able to run maven in debug mode to see the full error?

Comment: Maybe error from the Java compiler caused by your code?

Comment: I can add maven options, but can't find a Maven Debug option.
Also, my code is fine (At least, according to Eclipse)

Comment: Also, I have other projects on Maven as well, they do work.

Comment: `-e` enables full stacktrace output, `-X` full debug output

Comment: It tells me it doesn't know the options `-e` or `-x`.

Comment: It's still happening :'(

Comment: you can add the -X option.  you must be putting it in the wrong place.  - it goes in "goals and options" in the project config.

Comment: Never mind, fixed it. I'll post the answer in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time, I've found the problem.
It seems I was still using Referenced Libraries in my project, instead of using Maven's dependencies. Therefore, Maven didn't know what to do with certain aspects of my code, and errored out.

Comment: what do you mean by "referenced libraries"?  I'm just started getting the same error in Jenkins (with no descriptive compilation error messages); this just started happening in the last few days.  There's also a fairly old [bug here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10333) with the same issue.

Comment: @tdrury When you go to (assuming you're using Eclipse) your Project, Right click it, you'll see properties. In that window there's a tab called Libraries, under there is one called Referenced Libraries. I had to remove all of them, except Java itself, then fix all the errors that occured.

Comment: Lolmewn, thanks.  I use eclipse, but not for building.  We don't think the m2e plugin is "there yet". So we use 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' to generate projects then use eclipse's external programs to run maven (personally I don't do that either; I build from the command line).  So this isn't my issue.  Thanks for the info, though.  I'm going to post my issue as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the current version of the compiler plugin. This will show you your problem. I guess you have non plain ASCII characters like ä,ö,ü ... in your JavaDoc

Answer (score 0):

Just a blind shoot - do you have maven compiler configured properly for JDK >= 1.5? This is a pesky little thing, that I constantly keep forgetting about, but Maven uses JDK 1.4 as a default platform, so using Generics or any other feature from 1.5 ends up in compilation failure. Although in this case you should receive a more verbose output from Maven, so once again - it's a blind shoot.

Comment: Well, other projects do compile properly, so I don't think that's a problem (right?).

Also, I've fully copied the pom.xml (except for the groupId and artifactId) so it can't be the pom.xml..

Comment: Maven compiler is pom-specific, meaning each pom.xml can override it. So it could be that, you are suffering from the problem I described above. Could you paste <build> ... </build> section from your pom.xml? In worst case we will eliminate one problem ;)

Comment: Sure. Here it is:

`<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>`

Comment: Seems to be ok. Scratch that from your list.